# Deserialize XHTML to XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xhtml

I have the situation, that I need to serialize and deserialize XHTML code embedded into other xml content.
I manage to serialize the content with the following code, using XmlDocument. This however does not work with deserialization, I am getting an error that the XML is not formatted correct - which in my case rather means that the deserialization is not correct.

Do you have any hints for me?

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.81.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(TypeName="ATTRIBUTE-VALUE-XHTML", Namespace="http://www.omg.org/spec/ReqIF/20110401/reqif.xsd")]
public partial class ATTRIBUTEVALUEXHTML {

    ...

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("THE-VALUE")]
    public XHTMLCONTENT THEVALUE {
        get {
            return this.tHEVALUEField;
        }
        set {
            this.tHEVALUEField = value;
        }
    } 
}
```

And this is the XHTMLCONTENT class

```
public class XHTMLCONTENT : XmlDocument 
{

    public string Item { 
        get
        {
            return this.InnerXml;
        }
        set
        {
            this.LoadXml("<div xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">"+value+"</div>");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The source you use in the bottom snippet is not a complete XML file, but I'm not sure that's where the problem is. What is the value of `value`?

Comment: It is the value when writiing to the classes `Item` value. In my case a string containing xhtml. And I don't think that this is the main issue

Comment: To be absolutely sure, test (just once) with `value=""` and see if you get the same error.

Comment: I do, it doesn't change the behavior. The value is only relevant for serialisation as it is in the "set" part. What I am struggeling with is the DEserialization